# dependency implementation "org.apache.http.impl.client:client-DefaultHttpClient:4.2.5" cannot be found on android studio gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I added the dependency `org.apache.http.impl.client:client-DefaultHttpClient:4.2.6` on build.gradle for my android studio project. (Just for context, I am trying to use HttpClient to access help access data in php files). However, when I try to apply this dependency, I get an output message saying that my execution failed for the following reason:

```
8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.http.impl.client:client-DefaultHttpClient:4.2.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/http/impl/client/client-DefaultHttpClient/4.2.5/client-DefaultHttpClient-4.2.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/http/impl/client/client-DefaultHttpClient/4.2.5/client-DefaultHttpClient-4.2.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

The implementation is being searched for online, but I am not sure why this is the case, since I have a .jar file
located in the cache subfolder of a .gradle folder. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Build.Gradle code for reference:

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.http.impl.client:client-DefaultHttpClient:4.2.5'
    //implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.2.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your app level build.gradle:

```
 android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

Comment: I already have this included, is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: please show content of app level build.gradle too. it should include these  repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }